Get the max value of count(*) from 2 tables
I have two tables. 1 category and 1 business. I've been trying to learn how to selectively get the highest count of business in category for each state.
expected results
Thanks in advance for your help.

Which rdbms are you using? The problem can be solved by means of windowing functions but the syntax varies, according to which system you are running.

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Here is a possible solution for SQL-Server:
SELECT bstate, ccat, cnt FROM (
 SELECT b.state bstate, c.category ccat, count(*) cnt, 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b.state ORDER BY count(*) DESC) rn 
 FROM business b INNER JOIN category c ON b.id=c.business_id
 GROUP BY c.category, b.state
) tbl 
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY bstate, cnt desc

The window function ROW_NUMBER() assigns a unique ranking to each record applying the PARTITION and ORDER specifications of the OVER(...) block for this task.
The outer SELECT then simply needs to filter for records with rn=1 to exclude all other records.

What part of this query makes it SQL-Server-specific? As far as I see, the entire query is standard SQL and should be fine in all or at least the most RDBMS?

Hi @JonasMetzler, Thanks for the hint. I am glad to hear that these window functions are now widely available. That was not always the case and I only used them in a SQL-Server context.

Window functions are optional ISO/ANSI SQL features.
